# Can anyone tell me, how should I test out model? should I test it with each epoch or should we test at the end?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, conv-neural-network

Lets Say,  here is our train and test function where we train and test the model.

```
def train(all required variables):
    for input, target in train_loader:
       out = net(input)
       loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
       loss.backward()
       optimizer.step()
       acc = Accuracy(out, target)

def test(all required variables):
    for input, target in train_loader:
       outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)

        test_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
        total += targets.size(0)
        correct += predicted.eq(targets).sum().item()
        acc = 100.*correct/total
        return acc

if __name__ == '__main__':
     for epoch in range(start_epoch, start_epoch+200):
         train(epoch)
         acc = test(epoch)
         
         if acc > best_acc:
            print('Saving..')
           state = {'net': net.state_dict(),'acc': acc,
                   'epoch': epoch}
         torch.save(state, './checkpoint/ckpt.pth')
         best_acc = acc
```

Here in the above code, we train the model with the training dataset with each epoch and we are testing it on test dataset on each epoch and then saving the best checkpoint based on the accuracy of test dataset.

This same thing is happening in following GitHub repo; I have implemented almost 10 research paper in past 13 days, and I have seen the same code pattern in the all 10 papers.

1. https://github.com/winycg/HSAKD/blob/main/train_teacher_cifar.py
2. https://github.com/kuangliu/pytorch-cifar/blob/master/main.py

I have implemented the above 1st one paper, it is also following the above same pattern, I have trained it for 240 epoch as the author suggested in the Readme file. I have followed the all steps he written there. He has submitted the ***80.7% accuracy*** in his papers, to validate this accuracy I have trained it.

I have kept the model and all hyperparameter same, run it 5 times without any changes in the code and parameters.

**1st attempt = 80.69%**

**2nd attempt = 80.22%**

**3rd attempt = 80.93%**

**4rth attempt = 80.31%**

**5th attempt = 80.91%**

The average of all 5 attempts is 80.612%

why this accuracy is changing? If I have to submit it in my paper then how can I validate it?

Comment: I think the accuracies you're getting are very close to the one mentioned in the paper. What's the problem with the %0.1 difference? The fluctuation is normal because each random initialization will take you somewhere different.

Comment: With my proposed method, I am getting the following accuracy;

Comment: 1st attempt = 82.4%

2nd attempt = 82.22%

3rd attempt = 82.37%

4rth attempt = 81.99%

5th attempt = 82.29%

Comment: What should I submit? Can you tell me, is the above one method that I have written, is t right or wrong? where is the validation set in the above method? We are training and testing with each epoch

Answer (score 1):

The approach has some bias because the hyper-parameters (HPs) are tuned using the test set (no validation set seems to be around in the code). Yet, we may see it in some publications. So, it introduces some sort of data leakage. Be prepared to defend it if you want to go that way.

An alternative way would be using a separate validation set, tuning the HPs based on it and reporting the final result based on the test set.

Your accuracies are only slightly changing. I'd suggest presenting your results with mean +/- std, maybe with more attempts, e.g. 10 attempts. In this way, you also reflect the uncertainty associated with your trials.

Comment: Can you show some example how can I use separate validation set to tune my hyperparameter and avoid the biasness? and also how can I find the mean +/- std? can you find it for the above five values? I can't increase the attempts because each attempt takes so much time.

Comment: Just noticed, you use train_loader in your test function. It should've been test loader. I don't use torch, but you should have something like train_loader, validation_loader and test_loader. Divide your dataset into three pieces to do this. At each epoch, calculate & save both validation and test performance, but choose the best epoch by looking at only the validation performance. Report your test performance at the best epoch chosen by your validation set. For mean/std, just take the average of those five trials and calculate the std as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

Comment: Sorry that is mistake, that is the test_loader there in the test function. Cifar gives only test loader and train loader